# Cut list before last element that is equal to parameter

Tags: list, haskell

I need a function:

```hs
splitOn :: (Eq p) => p -> [p] -> ([p], [p])
```

So that:

```hs
splitOn 'b' ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'] = (['a', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'a'])
splitOn 'b' ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'] = (['a'], ['c', 'a'])
```

The argument passed is guaranteed to be in a consecutive block in the middle.

Is there a way to do `splitOn` on a single pass through the list?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find a way to search it.

Comment: Are you trying to write this from scratch, or to put together standard library functions to do it?

Comment: I am trying to put together standard library functions to do it.

Comment: Currently I am sorting the elements, so that I can split after the "divider" elements, and then delete it from the left list, but that seems like its not the best solution.

Comment: No, that's basically backwards. Why don't you explain what you're *actually* trying to do, to make sure this isn't an XY problem? What's the context?

Comment: Based on what you've said so far, take a look at `break` and `dropWhile`. But it might be possible to do better in context.

Comment: @dfeuer I have a list of 2-tuples that represent points, and I am trying to cut the list so that I can form each subtree of a bst, the subtrees must not contain the root. My current approach just returns the root and then I delete it with a `delete `. The points are sorted by one axis, but that seems to overclutter the function, so I am trying to remove that from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we do this, then we do that, and then we stop:

```
splitOn :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitOn b xs = g xs
  where
  g []                 = ([], [])
  g (x:xs) | x==b      = f xs
           | otherwise = first (x:) $ g xs
  f []                 = ([], [])
  f (x:xs) | x==b      = first (x:) $ f xs
           | otherwise = ([], x:xs)
```

Answer (score -1):

From my vague understanding, it sounds like you have a set of points you want to store in a somewhat balanced binary search tree indexed by the first components. To take an off-the-shelf balanced binary search tree, this could look something like the following:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S

-- | A `PointTree` stores, for each `a`, a set of second
-- components `b`.
newtype PointTree a b = PT
  { getPT :: Map a (Set b) }

fromList :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> PointTree a b
fromList = PT . M.fromListWith Set.union . map S.singleton

toList :: PointTree a b -> [(a, b)]
toList (PT m) = [(a, b) | (a, bs) <- M.assocs m, b <- S.elems bs]
```

The above will discard duplicate points. If you want to keep those, you can use lists instead of sets.

Now if you want to build your very own balanced tree, you'll have to pick one. `Data.Map` and `Data.Set` use Adams trees (approximately weight-balanced). You could also use AVL trees, red-black trees, etc.

Comment: I need `splitOn` other info is context, I want to know how to create that function, please, help me with that. Thanks you